# Logging in using VPN in Windows 8

Tags: vpn, login, domain, windows-8, pptp

Just installed Windows 8 Enterprise on my work laptop.

I have configured my VPN connection (PPTP) like I had in Windows 7, but for some reason, I cannot find out where to select that I want to dial-up to my workplace before trying to logon to the domain.

Any ideas?

/GurliGebis

EDIT: I'm talking about logging in BEFORE logging into Windows, not after :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Left click the networking icon on your task bar, and a fly-out menu shows up from the right side of the screen.
2. The VPN connection is up towards the top. Left-click that, and a connection button appears.

For when you first log on, there's a "network logon" icon next to the "ease of access" icon on the lower left of the screen.

(This may have been set up by my corporate IT, YMMV)

Comment: I'm talking about connecting to VPN before logging into Windows.

In Windows 7, I could click "Change User", and click on a small icon down to the right on the login screen, and select to dial the VPN before logging into Windows.

Comment: Oh! Sorry. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Hmm, thats interresting, on my machine, there is only the Ease of access icon in the lower left corner.

What kind of VPN are you using? PPTP?

Comment: Nevermind, I feel like such an i**ot right now, since it is right there on the button when I click the back arrow.

Comment: Not at all, it's a new OS so some things are going to take some getting used to. :)

Comment: @MarkAllen My VPN connection doesn't show there, what can I do to make it?

Comment: @zyboxenterprises It's not obvious but click the little icon on your system tray that looks like a monitor with a network or power cable sticking up. That'll open a menu on the left side that says "Connections". On my PC, the VPN connection shows up there and I can click "Connect". Do the same thing later after it's connected and it'll say "Disconnect".

Answer (score 0):

If a Win 8 domain joined machine you need to re-enable Ctrl+Alt+Del it then gives you the option to authenticate to the domain using the VPN before logon after selecting "switch user".  It is outlined in the following link:
http://blog.lan-tech.ca/2013/03/02/windows-8-connect-to-vpn-before-logon/

Answer (score 0):

If you setup the VPN using the "Metro" interface in Windows 8, there is no option to share it with other users. Instead you need to use the "Set up a new connection or network" option under "Network and Sharing Center", which is outlined in [these screenshots](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-to-a-VPN) from Windows 7. On one of the "Connect to a workplace" pages you will find a option to "Allow other people to use this connection" which when enabled will allow you to use an icon on the login page to connect to the VPN.